# Reference an object that instantiated another?

Tags: c#, reference, constructor

I have a class called Star, and it has a

```
public List<Planet> Planets = new List<Planet>();
```

There is a method that creates the Planets with the variables needed, though I want some of the information about the star accessible in the planet class.

right now there are 4 variables I construct the 'Planet Class' with but I need about 6 of the variables from the 'Star Class' available in the 'Planet Class'.

Is there a way to have a reference to the parent star in the planet class? and how would I pass the reference to the Planet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can include a reference in the Planet class to the Star.  You can then create a constructor that takes that reference, like so:

```
public class Planet
{
   private Star orbits;

   ...

   public Planet(Star orbits)
   {
      this.orbits = orbits;
      ...
   }

   ...
}
```

You can then instantiate it from in Star like this:

```
public List<Planet> Planets = new List<Planet>(this);
```

Comment: does the "private Star orbits;" just point to the parent star? or is it making a copy and taking up double the memory of the computer?

Comment: As @user1341210 mentions, this points to the Star object.  In C# (and, in fact, object oriented languages in general) when you see a variable which appears to be the type of a class, if is actually a Reference.  This means that it holds a handle to the location of an instance (object) of that class type.  When you use the new keyword you create an instance, and this returns a reference.  That reference is what is usually saved in this type of reference variable.

Comment: @aring `(and, in fact, object oriented languages in general)` is patently false - see C++.

Comment: @IskarJarak It's true that it's not universally applied, though note that I said "in general".  Also, C++ is not a strictly OO language, it's a hybrid language and as such contains significant influences from outside of the OO paradigm.  C#, Java and Smalltalk are all examples of strictly OO languages, all of which use the model I described.  It's not universal, but it is generally the case.

Comment: @aring "In general" means it applies to most or all cases. Given that a _very_ prominent case (C++) does not fit your generalisation, I don't think your claim is helpful to readers as they might easily assume it holds in a case where it doesn't. That's why I called you out on it, although my wording was a bit strong. FWIW, Java and C# (as well as C++) are also multiparadigm, and are definitely not good examples of `strictly OO languages`. (Smalltalk is though.)

Comment: @IskarJarak To my understanding, a language is strictly OO if it requires you to write programs in OO fashion.  To my knowledge, both C# and Java follow that convention, and thus are strictly OO.  Is there a different definition or information I'm missing which would make those not qualify?  If so, I'd love to see it, thanks.

Comment: @aring There are a ton of things to cover here, but...
1) In Java, primitives are not objects. Not every type in the language is an object, end of story. Moving on from the low hanging fruit...
2) OO is a paradigm, and whereas Smalltalk really only involves OOP (to my knowledge, at least), Java and C# both allow or include the use of other programming paradigms (e.g. procedural in C#).
Don't confuse a class-based language with enforcing of object-oriented design. I can't choose not to have any classes in my Java program, but I can certainly choose not to code in an object oriented manner.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to accomplish this, just one idea:

What about making a parameter for your contstructor like:

```
private List<Star> _solarSystem;   

Planet(List<Star> solarSystem)
{
    this._solarSystem = solarSystem;
}
```

From OO point of view it would be better to have instead of the list a class. I assume the code you have posted is also in some class, so how is your class called ?

```
private SolarSystem _solarSystem;   

Planet(SolarSystem solarSystem)
{
    this._solarSystem = solarSystem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical solution is to inject an interface that the class implements into the dependent class (dependency injection).  Something like this for your case:

```
internal interface IStar
{
    void Method1();
    string Property1 { get; }
    ...
}

internal abstract class Star : IStar
{
    protected Star()
    {
        foreach(string planetName in planetNames)
        {
            Planet p = new Planet(planetName, this);
            Planets.Add(p);
        }
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        ...
    }

    public string Property1
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }
}

internal class Planet
{
    string name;
    IStar parentStar;

    internal Planet(string name, IStar parentStar)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.parentStar = parentStar;
    }
}
```

Doing it in this fashion allows you to pass in different classes that implement `IStar` if needed.  Maybe you have the base abstract class `Star`, which is inherited by `ClassAStar`, `DwarfStar`, etc.  The `Planet` doesn't care what kind of star you pass in, as long as it implements the `IStar` interface.  This promotes loose coupling, making your code easier to maintain.

Comment: So is the IStar in the Planet class just a reference? like a pointer? or is it copying the IStar that was passed in taking up more space?

Comment: @JosephDour Since `Star` is declared as a `class`, it is a reference type, therefore `Planet` is just keeping a pointer reference to it.  It is not copying the entire value contents of the `Star`.

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary like this:

```
IDictionary<Star, IList<Planet>> planetSystems = new Dictionary<Star, IList<Planet>>();
```